# Error when knit to HTML file

Tags: r, knitr

I'm having this problem: all code chunks run fine. But when trying to knit to HTLM file the error message appear. How to solve this?

```
movies <- mutate(movies, feature_film = ifelse(title_type =="Feature Film", "yes", "no")) 
movies$feature_film <- as.factor(movies$feature_film)
```

> Error in mutate_(.data,.dots = lazyeval : : lazy_dots(. . .) : object ´movies´not found calls :  . . . withVisible -> eval -> eval -> mutate -> mutate Execution halted

Comment: My guess is that `movies` is in your environment so R finds it when running the chunks in the console. You need to make sure `movies` is available in the rmarkdown

Answer (score 1):

Likely the markdown document doesn't have the object loaded. This isn't somewhere in the document:

```
load(file="your_data.RData")
```

EDIT: comment already saying pretty much this, apologies.